# Passing one variable from one class to another

Tags: python, class, for-loop, oop, k-fold

i am take the no. of iteration in for loop running from a different class.

```
for e in range(1,EPOCHS+1 ):
g=0 
for j in range (jin):
   g=g+1
   print(g)
   train_epoch_loss = 0
   train_epoch_acc = 0   

   p1=cross(g)
   #pw=pq.save(g)
   #p1=pq.get()
   model.train()
```

and saving it in this class and need to use that value.

```
class cross():  
c=0
def init__ (self,value):
    self.v = value
    print('i entered the classs')

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x_trainval):
    c=c+1
  #      e1=num()
    x_train,x_val=x[train_index],x[test_index]
    y_train,y_val=y[train_index],y[test_index]
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    print("epoch",c)
            #     print(e1.__getitem__())
    if (v == c):
        print("compare")
        break

train_dataset = classifierdataset(torch.from_numpy(x_train).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_train).long())
val_dataset = classifierdataset(torch.from_numpy(x_val).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_val).long()) 
test_dataset = classifierdataset(torch.from_numpy(x_test).float(), torch.from_numpy(y_test).long())   


train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

val_loader = DataLoader(dataset = val_dataset, batch_size = 1)

test_loader = DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset , batch_size = 1)
print("train",x_train,"val",x_val)
```

Now the issues i am having is how to use the set value in the same class.

Comment: `def __getitem__(self):` doesnt make sense,btw, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: `if num.__getitem__== c:` ?? Why are you using `__getitem__` here? Why is there a `num` class at all? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Your class structure and indenting is broken. Can you clean the code with indents.  

and show where u are declaring variables like c , v , x_trainval.

Answer (score 0):

just put a return statement and take the values accordingly to the return statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if you can access obj.value within other methods or self.value within the same class methods .

Maybe this will help you ,

[https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd#:~:text=Class%20variables%20are%20shared%20across,surprising%20behaviour%20in%20our%20code](https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd#:%7E:text=Class%20variables%20are%20shared%20across,surprising%20behaviour%20in%20our%20code).

Accessing an instance variable within an instance method (a method that accepts self as first argument) -
Correct way -

```
class Student:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # Instance variable
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def show(self):
        print('Name:', self.name, 'Age:', self.age)
```

Wrong way -

```
class Student:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # Instance variable
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # instance method access instance variable
    def show(self):
        print('Name:', name, 'Age:', age)

student_obj.show()
```

gives

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

within some other method you need to have the obj available :

```
c_obj = cross(5)

def any_other_method(c: cross) -> None:
    print("value is ", c.v)

any_other_method(c_obj) prints "value is 5"
```